# Composite Control: Label for: associatecontrolID not generating FULL control id

Tags: asp.net

I have a composite control where i set Label's associatedControlID to ID of textbox. But the generated control id looks like this:

```
ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContent_TextboxControlId_
```

It should have been:

```
ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContent_TextboxControlId_**ct100**
```

The last part is not generated correctly.

I've created a method in my base and I am calling given code in OnLoad(). I also tried OnPreRender(), but it didn't work.

```
base.SetAssociatedControlID(id);


public void SetAssociatedControlID(string id)
{
    label.AssociatedControlID = id
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using ClientIDMode="Static" , in your control markup?

Comment: ClientIDMode doesn't work I already tried

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code please?